# Is it ok to flag answers as "low quality" because they are wrong?

Tags: discussion, flags, wrong-answers

I recently asked a question that got a quick answer that was wrong.

After a few comments with the answerer, he stopped defending his position (because it does not work).

But the answer is still there to mislead others.  So I am left wondering if I should do anything about it or just let the eventual downvoting take its course.

Answer (score 13):

Downvoting is the correct response to 'incorrect' answers, perhaps along with appropriate commenting. Users with 20k can vote to delete extremely 'wrong' answers, but you should not flag a moderator for them.

Comment: +1 Moderator's comment on one of my old declined flag: *declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*

Comment: 20k users should also not be deleting answers just for being wrong; you should just downvote/comment.

Comment: @Servy I probably needed to use a different word than 'extremely', such as 'dangerously'... not just 'wrong', but really bad in some way (yet, short of what we might usually flag).

Comment: I can see the OP's point. This site touts itself as a Q&A site, where everything should be straightforward and to the point. And it doesn't like long discussions and "chatty" or off-topic answers. But plain wrong answers are OK to keep?

Comment: @MrLister If wrong answers are down voted, yes; they are OK to keep. But the question was specifically about *flagging a mod* for incorrect answers. That should not be done.

Answer (score 7):

## DOWNVOTE

Whether an answer is right or wrong is not a thing a moderator should look into. They are not here as judge on the correctness of answers. They have other serious issues to deal with. They just work for maintaining peace and order in the community.

Let the community decide (rather than an individual) the acceptability of an answer. The right way to deal with a wrong answer is to **down vote**. This is the power SE gives to its community. So use it wisely. Also IMHO you should comment before your down-vote so that the OP can understand what is wrong with the post and (hopefully) he can rectify it.

Using FLAG in these cases is likely to return you the result as @hims056 commented,

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer